# Make 4 digit integer from one, two, or three digits integer in PHP

Tags: php, integer

I'am doing a call to a database to retrieve an ID of a specific item. Usually there are the ids like: `1, 2, 14, 23, ...`. I need to get the ID from a DB and output it 4 digit number.

For exemple:
My result ID is: `1`. Now i when i have this value, i want it to become `0001`. Or if my result id is `13`, it should became `0013`, etc.

How can i achieve that with php without changing the real ID in database?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You want to **zerofill** an integer.

You could either do `sprintf('%04u', $n)` or `str_pad($n, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)`.

Comment: Is there any difference in using one or another ? I'am on PHP5 and first one is not working.

Comment: @aspirinemaga: You're probably doing something wrong then (see http://codepad.org/nzEgZ9nP). Regarding the difference, they both do the same thing - `sprintf` comes from the `C` world but `str_pad` is more powerful as it provides left + right padding and you also don't need to worry about escaping meta-characters such as `%`. Also, you can pad with strings longer than 1 character in length (I'm not sure if you can do the same with `sprintf`).

Comment: Thank you very much your comment. Will take a better look inside my code as it just won't work with `sprintf()`

Comment: Oh sorry, of course it doesn't worked, i replaced `echo` with `sprintf`, i thought `sprintf` is the same as `echo` but with another functions.

Comment: @aspirinemaga: No =) for that you can use `printf`, which is the same as `print` but with the placeholder magic.

Comment: `$now=microtime(true);
$t=sprintf('%03u', $n);
$diff=microtime(true)-$now;
echo "time for sprintf is: $diff ... result is: $t<br>";
$now=microtime(true);
$t=str_pad($n, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$diff=microtime(true)-$now;
echo "time for str_pad is: $diff ... result is: $t<br>";
` time for sprintf is: 2.59876251221E-005 ... result is: 011
time for str_pad is: 1.47819519043E-005 ... result is: 011

Answer (score 11):

Same as always.

```
sprintf("%04d", $num)
```

Comment: it's not working, it just wont output anything at all, even error, just empty field. Am I using it right?: `<?php sprintf("%04d", $item->id);?>`

Comment: `$modified_id = sprintf("%04d", $item->id);`

Comment: @aspirinemaga: It only returns the string. You're responsible for outputting it.

Answer (score 5):

You want the [PHP strpad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function:

```
<?php
$input = 1;
echo str_pad($input, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);  // produces "0001"
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it inside of MySQL query, here it is

```
SELECT LPAD(id, 4, '0') as modified_id FROM table;
```

Comment: yeah, and any performance difference between using PHP and MySQL methods ?